# Calculating SQL Average with non-numeric data in Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have this SQL query that is failing on this nvarchar, even though it seems to me that it is properly guarded for a cast to work. I am trying to get the average of the values for correctly formatted numerical values on a database that I only have read access to.

```
select TagName, count(TagName) as Freq,
       sum(isnumeric(value)) as GoodNums,
       avg(case isnumeric(value) when 1 then cast(value as numeric) else 0 end) as "Avg",
       Min(Timestamp) as StartTime,
       Max(Timestamp) as EndTime 
 from HH_Data_9 group by TagName
```

However I never really completely grokked the SQL syntax for combinations of CASE, aggregate functions, and GROUP_BY, so maybe I am just writing it wrong (Tried quite a few things before posting this). Note that the "GoodNums" column works and is giving reasonable answers but when I add the "Avg" column to the query the whole thing errors out of with:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.
```

This is Microsoft SQL Server 2014 by the way. Any ideas?

Comment: `isnumeric()` is not perfect -- values like `$` (currency symbol), `,`, `.` (separators only) are also numbers for it. Maybe here is the problem?

Comment: use try_cast instead of case expression. It is available on SQL Server 2012 and above.

Comment: ok, that worked Jesus, thanks. If you submit it as a an answer with code I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Still waiting for you (Jesús López) to post an answer that I can mark as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Just want to caution that this approach is very dangerous. Consider the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
    (
      FieldType NVARCHAR(50) ,
      FieldValue NVARCHAR(50)
    )
GO

INSERT  INTO dbo.TestTable
VALUES  ( 'INT', '5' ),
        ( 'INT', '15' ),
        ( 'MONEY', '5.5' )


SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.TestTable
WHERE   FieldType = 'INT'
        AND CAST(FieldValue AS INT) > 10
```

On my machine this query works, but the thing here is that many assumes that this predicate will evaluate from left to right. But this is incorrect. SQL Server engine may decide to evaluate this expression from right to left. And in this case you will get `Conversion failed` error. It's called `ALL-AT-ONCE` principle. However in your example this is not applicable, but just wanted to mention.